# Excel: What code should I write to select multiple cells directly above cells that have a certain value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of numbers in a certain order. In that column, some of the numbers are 99999999. I need to select the cells that are directly above this number. Here is an example, I need to select all the cells highlighted bold:

- 63012097
- 63012097
- 63012097
- 63133638
- **63133638**
- 99999999
- 99999999
- 63048742
- 63048742
- 63020783
- 63066755
- **63167680**
- 99999999
- 99999999
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- 63033618
- **63033618**
- 99999999
- 99999999
- 63005597
- **63005597**
- 99999999
- 99999999
- 63099456
- 63099456
- 63099456
- 63099456
- **63099456**
- 99999999
- 99999999
- 63029683
- 63029683

I just wanted to show the data as a column so ignore the bullet points ;)

I have 723,950 rows of this so it isn't really possible to do it manually either. Can anyone help?

Thank you! :D

Comment: Why oh why do you want to do this?

Comment: With this much data you are bound to hit a limit of Excel: In Excel 2010 the maximum number of _ranges_ that may be selected is 2048 ([see this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)) Earlier version this limit is probably lower.  As others have commented, selecting is probably the first step in a larger task.  If you post what your real requiremetns are we may be able to offer some advice...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the cells once you've selected them.  If you just want them highlighted like in your example, you can use Excel's conditional formatting feature.

Just select the column of data. In Excel 2007, go to Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule....  From there, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".  Where A1 is the first entry in your column, enter this formula:

```
=AND(OFFSET(A1,1,0)=99999999,A1<>99999999)
```

Set the format to Bold or whatever other highlight you'd prefer.

Comment: I don't think the OP actually wants to change the font of the cells in bold. Just to select the cells. Why? Beats me! Anyway, +1

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't really want to select them.  You probably want to do something else to them, which would change this code.  But this will select them.

```
Sub Select999()

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rSelect As Range
    Dim rSearch As Range

    Const lFIND As Long = 99999999

    Set rSearch = Sheet1.Columns(1)
    Set rFound = rSearch.Find(lFIND, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAdd = rFound.Address
        Do
            If rFound.Row > 1 Then
                If rFound.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> lFIND Then
                    If rSelect Is Nothing Then
                        Set rSelect = rFound.Offset(-1, 0)
                    Else
                        Set rSelect = Union(rSelect, rFound.Offset(-1, 0))
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            Set rFound = rSearch.FindNext(rFound)

        Loop Until rFound.Address = sFirstAdd
    End If

    rSelect.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this. There may be more efficient ways though...

```
Sub SelectAbove99999999()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sel As String
    Dim above As String

    ' initialize
    Set cell = Range("A1")
    sel = ""

    ' do until a blank cell
    While cell.Text <> ""

        ' coords of the cell above this
        above = "A" & (cell.Row - 1)

        ' if this cell contains the key value
        If cell = "99999999" Then

            ' if above there isn't the key value
            If Range(above) <> "99999999" Then

                ' add this cell to the interesting ones
                sel = sel & above & ","

            End If

        End If

        ' next cell
        Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)

    Wend

    ' strip last comma
    sel = Left(sel, Len(sel) - 1)

    ' select
    Range(sel).Select

End Sub
```

Note: it assumes values are listed in column A and are terminated by a blank cell.

Comment: If the person has a ton of ranges to cover using a string will not be sufficient. A better way is to use union with ranges.